# кодировка String

Tags: java, android, кодировка

Добрый день!

Пытаюсь настроить апи яндекс.переводчика внутри приложения на android.
При передаче слов латиницей все работает хорошо, но как только я пытаюсь перевести с русского на любой другой язык, в ответ приходят знаки вопроса вместо перевода. С английского на русский переводит нормально.

```
    link = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + myKey + "&text=" + word + "&lang=" + baslang + "-" + learnlang;
```

В случае если word - кириллическая строка, в окне дебага все показывается нормально, но на сервер заходит по адресу
https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20150902T132259Z.448e3d1d80a9ea8e.5584e6a80be79d826cde897c5204d6eacbfae45e&text=????&lang=ru-en, то есть вместо текста знаки вопроса, соответственно яндекс присылает такое "слово" непереведенным - ????

сам код:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
            try {
                URL url = new URL(link);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }
```

Как сделать так чтоб слово оставалось в кириллице?

Comment: А вы уверены, что переменная `word` содержит корректные данные?

Comment: Код-то покажите. Как вы конкретно отправляете запрос на сайт?

Comment: Если эта переменная содержит кириллические символы, то все плохо, если только латиница все работает

Comment: И зачем вы ваш ключ засветили в вопросе? Чтобы все желающие им пользовались? :-)

Comment: ключ заблокировал уже, они бесплатно раздаются)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать `URLEncoder.encode`:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

link = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + myKey + "&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(word, "UTF-8") + "&lang=" + baslang + "-" + learnlang;
```

PS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/607176/4928642

Comment: UnsupportedEncodingException